# GNU make with many target directories

Tags: makefile, release-management, gnu-make, build-management

I have to integrate the generation of many HTML files in an existing `Makefile`.
The problem is that the HTML files need to reside in many different directories.
My idea is to write an implicit rule that converts the source file (*.st) to the corresponding html file

```
%.html: %.st
    $(HPC) -o $@ $<
```

and a rule that depends on all html files

```
all: $(html)
```

If the HTML file is not in the builddir, *make* doesn't find the implicit rule: `*** No rule to make target`.
If I change the implicit rule like so

```
$(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/01/%.html: %.st  
    $(HPC) -o $@ $<
```

it's found, but then I have to have an implicit rule for nearly every file in the project.
According to [Implicit Rule Search Algorithm](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search) in the GNU `make` manual, rule search works like this:

> 1. Split the entire target name *t* into a directory part, called *d*, and the rest, called *n*. For
>      example, if *t* is `src/foo.o`,
>      then *d* is `src/`,
>      and *n* is `foo.o`.
> 2. Make a list of all the pattern rules one of whose targets matches *t* or *n*.
>      If the target pattern contains a slash,
>      it is matched against *t*;
>      otherwise, against *n*.

Why is the implicit rule not found, and what would be the most elegant solution, assuming GNU `make` is used?

Here is a stripped down version of my `Makefile`:

```
rootdir  = /home/user/project/doc
HPC      = /usr/local/bin/hpc

html = $(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/01/some.html

%.html: %.st
    $(HPC) -o $@ $<

#This works, but requires a rule for every output dir
#$(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/01/%.html: %.st  
#   $(HPC) -o $@ $<

.PHONY: all
all: $(html)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Maria Shalnova I like recursive make (though I disagree with "Recursive Make Considered Harmful"), and in general it's better to make something HERE from a source THERE, not the reverse. But if you must, I suggest a slight improvement: have generateHtml generate only the RULE, not the COMMANDS.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I found so far is to generate an implicit rule per target directory via [foreach-eval-call](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function), as explained in the [GNU `make` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). I have no idea how this scales to a few thousand target directories, but we will see...

If you have a better solution, please post it!

Here is the code:

```
rootdir  = /home/user/project/doc
HPC      = /usr/local/bin/hpc

html = $(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/01/some.html \
       $(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/02/some.html

targetdirs = $(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/01 \
             $(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/02

define generateHtml
 $(1)/%.html: %.st
    -mkdir -p $(1)
    $(HPC) -o $$@ $$<
endef   

$(foreach targetdir, $(targetdirs), $(eval $(call generateHtml, $(targetdir))))

.PHONY: all
all: $(html)
```

Comment: I can't see any other solution than using some form of call-foreach-eval. GNU make does not cope well with this kind of directory layouts. (In fact, the original make more or less assumed that you had all your source code in a single directory.)

Answer (score 4):

Your active implicit rule makes `$(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/01/some.html` depend on `$(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/01/some.st`. If `$(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/01/some.st` doesn't exist then the rule won't be used/found.

The commented out rule makes `$(rootdir)/build/doc/2009/06/01/some.html` depend on `some.st`.

One solution is to make you're source layout match your destination/result layout.

Another option is to create the rules as required with [`eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function). But that will be quite complicated:

```
define HTML_template
 $(1) : $(basename $(1))
      cp $< $@
endef

$(foreach htmlfile,$(html),$(eval $(call HTML_template,$(htmlfile))))
```

Comment: That would work, but unfortunately the source layout is fixed and the real Makefile uses VPATH.

Answer (score 3):

An other possibility is to have the commando `make` call itself recursively with the argument -C with every output directory. 
Recursive `make` is somewhat the standard way to deal with subdirectories, but beware of the implications mentioned in the article "Recursive Make Considered Harmful"

Comment: OK, recursive make didn't come to my mind. Your solution would be quite portable.