# Makefile error message: Nothing to be done

Tags: makefile

please I need your help!

In order to get a list of thumbnails associated with a list of photos, I've use the following Makefile (the project's directory has 2 subdirectories thumbs and pictures)

```
all: $(patsubst pictures/%.jpg, thumbs/%.jpg, $(wilcard pictures/*.jpg))
thumbs/%.jpg: pictures/%.jpg
    convert -thumbnail 100 $< $*
```

The problem is that I always get  the same error message "Nothing to be done for 'all'", as if there was no dependencies. :(
Has anybody an explanation for that?

Comment: Sorry, I mean Error message and not meddae :p

Comment: I changed the title for you, but this is your question, so you are actually able to edit it. `:)`

Comment: Continue reading here __GNU make with many target directories__ (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934127/gnu-make-with-many-target-directories)

Answer (score 4):

It is a simple typo: just add the missing **d** to `$(wildcard ...)`

Make does not throw an error when you make a call to a function that does not exist, so the result of that function call is simply an empty string. This makes your `all` target have no dependencies, and there you are!

For future reference, I found this error by adding the following line at the beginning of the makefile:

```
$(info $(patsubst pictures/%.jpg, thumbs/%.jpg, $(wilcard pictures/*.jpg)))
```

The [`$(info ...)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) function will print out to the console, which can be *very* useful for debugging. In this case, it printed a blank line. To debug further, I tried this:

```
$(info $(wilcard pictures/*.jpg))
```

Which *also* dumped an empty string. At that point, all it took was some careful squinting `:)`

Comment: Thank you very very very much :) I haven't noticed that the d was missing :p